# Multiple Docker images in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Here is my problem setup with GitLab and its integrated CI service. I have a current GitLab 8.1. and a gitlabci-multi-runner (0.6.2) with Docker support. After extending the ubuntu:precise image to include `git` and `build-essentials` (now named *precise:base*) I got the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` running:

```
image: precise:base
before_script:
   - apt-get install --yes cmake libmatio-dev libblas-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   - apt-get install --yes libarchive-dev liblzma-dev

build:
  script:
    - mkdir build/
    - cd build
    - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
    - make
```

Now my question is how to include more jobs on different images? Because I need to check if the code compiles (and later on works) on different operating systems like Ubuntu Precise, Ubuntu Trusty, CentOS 6, CentOS 7. To reduce the work I think the best way is to provide different Docker images as base.

Now the questions is how must the `.gitlab-ci.yml` look like to support this?

Comment: have a look to extend keyword https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can [define the image to use per job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml).

For instance:

```
before_script:
   - apt-get install --yes cmake libmatio-dev libblas-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   - apt-get install --yes libarchive-dev liblzma-dev

build:precise:
  image: precise:base
  script:
    - mkdir build/
    - cd build
    - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
    - make

build:trusty:
  image: trusty:base
  script:
    - mkdir build/
    - cd build
    - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
    - make
```

Comment: is there a way to define two images per job? I need a gradle:jdk11 image as well as a mysql image for a particular testing job

Comment: @Hemil did you get a way to use 2 images ?

Comment: @buckybarns there is a way to use services in gitlab. So I can use one image for jdk add specify a service for mysql. Unfortunately, I have abandoned that project but you can find resources on how to add services in gitlab

Comment: @Hemil i used a custom gitlab runner instead. Since I had a lot of configurations to be added on gitlab runner.

Answer (score 50):

Your can use [`Anchors`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#anchors) to make the `.gitlab-ci.yml` more clearly. (But this need GitLab 8.6 and GitLab Runner v1.1.1.)

Like this:

```
before_script:
   - apt-get install --yes cmake libmatio-dev libblas-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   - apt-get install --yes libarchive-dev liblzma-dev

.build_template: &build_definition
  script:
    - mkdir build/
    - cd build
    - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
    - make

build:precise:
  image: precise:base
  <<: *build_definition

build:trusty:
  image: trusty:base
  <<: *build_definition
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is exactly what I'm searching for. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write 2 work steps for Centos6 and Centos7. The main difference is that different versions of Centos need to set different Repo source addresses when downloading dependency packages; or the versions of dependency packages that can be used , are different in the 2 systems.

Because the YUM repository of Centos6 has been removed from the official server, you can no longer use the default repository to update or download. You can refer to this article to modify the repository for Centos6:

- https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol

After confirming your operation processes in the two systems, write them in two different script files, such as `build_for_el6.sh` and `build_for_el7.sh`.

Then add 2 workflows for `Centos6` and `Centos7` in gitlab-ci.yaml, like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build_el7
  - build_el6

before_script:
  - do something

build_el7:
  image: centos:7
  script:
    - sh -x build_for_el7.sh
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - builds
    expire_in: 7 days
  only:
    - tags # This stage will only be executed when the `git push --tags` command is executed and new tags are pushed to gitlab.
  tags:
    - centos7 # Only used to filter execution runners

build_el6:
  image: centos:6
  script:
    - sh -x build_for_el6.sh
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - builds
    expire_in: 7 days
  only:
    - tags # This stage will only be executed when the `git push --tags` command is executed and new tags are pushed to gitlab.
  tags:
    - centos6 # Only used to filter execution runners
```

You can also follow the steps in the `build_for_elx.sh` script to write different `Dockerfile` and customize a `Docker image` for yourself. If you are interested, you can refer to this article:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

This requires you to perform the image building operation on the `gitlab-ci-runner` device, and then you need to add 2 `runner instances` and use 2 different `Docker images` to work respectively. If everything goes well, you can modify `gitlab-ci.yml`, just specify 2 `gitlab-ci runner` in the 2 work steps respectively. You can refer to this document about `gitlab-ci runner`:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).